# VBA Why is my macro reading column 5 instead of 3

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro to insert a row between cells when their values are different. I have 9 columns in my data and the data starts at row 2. I want my macro to check all the values down column 3 (also known as column "C") and as it goes through, if the value changes (i.e. 2, 2, 2, 3, 3) it will insert a row between the changed value (i.e. 2, 2, 2, INSERT ROW, 3, 3). The problem is, my macro is reading column 5(E) not 3(C). What is wrong with it, I can't figure it out! The reason I know this too is because I placed a msgbox to spit the value of the cell and it matches everything in column 5 but not 3. Here is my code:

```
Sub Dividers()

Dim DividerRange As Range, lastrow As Long, k As Integer, counter As Integer

lastrow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

Set DividerRange = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastrow, 3))
counter = 0

For k = 2 To DividerRange.Count
MsgBox DividerRange(k + counter, 3).Value
    If DividerRange(k + counter, 3).Value = DividerRange(k + counter - 1, 3).Value Then
    DividerRange(k + counter, 3).EntireRow.Insert
    counter = counter + 1
    Else
End If
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Range("C1").Cells(1,3) is E1.  `DividerRange` is already a range in ColumnC, so by indexing the column to "3" you're actually stepping outside of `DividerRange` and two columns over.  `MsgBox DividerRange(k + counter).Value` is what you want.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DividerRange(k + counter, 3).Value` is a relative reference. `DividerRange` is a range starting at `C2`, so when you ask for the `(i,j)`th cell, i.e. `(i,3)` you get something from column E where `j`th columns would be: (C = 1, D = 2, E = 3)

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. All that should change in that is the row, right?

Comment: So if I change it from 3 to 1, then it should work? Wait no that's not possible because I place the message box after I say `k=2 to DividerRange.count` and it gives me the 5th row value. But then this means that the k + counter is screwing it up somehow, but I'm not sure exactly how

Comment: When you ask for `DividerRange(i,j)` you are asking for the `i`th Row/`j`th Column _within_ `DividerRange`, not within the `Worksheet`. Think of `DividerRange` as a subset of the `Cells` in the `Worksheet`

Comment: You can test this with `Debug.Print DividerRange(k + counter, 3).Address` to see what address you are actually referencing

Comment: AH I see what you mean. Ok so then just take out the column and it should work, correct? Thank you! I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it quite a lot, there's no need for the Range or Range count, or counter:

```
Sub Dividers()

    Dim lastrow As Long, k As Integer

    lastrow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    For k = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(k, 3).Value <> Cells(k - 1, 3).Value Then
            Cells(k, 3).EntireRow.Insert

            'Now skip a row so we don't compare against the new empty row
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```